# What happens when password of SQL service account is changed after successful login

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am curious to know what happens when we change the password of sql service account after successfully logging into the sql server. I observed that sql server was still accessible although the password with which I logged into the server is no more same. But after sometime, it started to refuse connection needing me to enter the new credentials. Why were the changes not reflected immediately when I changed the password(it took some time for them to be effective[about 15 mins])? Is it that SQL caches the credentials and periodically refreshes that cache?

Thanks,
Jack

Answer (score 0):

Once a connection is established and secured, it will continue to be usable even if the password changes mid-session. This is standard for just about any online situation, including SQL Server. The only alternative is to find all existing sessions that are being used with that set of credentials that were changed and close their connections (stopping any currently executing queries). This is typically not ideal, so the tradeoff is made.

As for why you saw a delay, it likely has to do with your application code rather than any sort of "caching" of credentials.